# how to send a attachment email using jsp?

Tags: jsp, email-attachments

I need to send a attachment email using jsp and used below code but error is occurred as unable to send message. Use this same code no error occurred in compile time. but in run time, error occured as unable to send message. coding is:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.mail.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%
   String result;
   String to = "abcd@gmail.com"; 
   String from = "mcmohd@gmail.com";   
   String host = "localhost";
   Properties properties = System.getProperties(); 
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
     Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

   try{

      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);   

      message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));   

      message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                               new InternetAddress(to));   

      message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");   

      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();    

      messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");          

      Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();    

      multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);    

      messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
      String filename = "file.txt";
      DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
      messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
      messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
      multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


      message.setContent(multipart );


      Transport.send(message);
      String title = "Send Email";
      result = "Sent message successfully....";
   }catch (MessagingException mex) {
      mex.printStackTrace();
      result = "Error: unable to send message....";
   }
%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Send Attachement Email using JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Send Attachement Email using JSP</h1>
</center>
<p align="center">
<% 
   out.println("Result: " + result + "\n");
%>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you try giving absolute file path for file.txt

Comment: I would like to add that having logic not related to presentation in a JSP is considered Very Bad Practise™. It makes the whole application harder to maintain. Use a MVC framework instead. Some of them offer means to send emails in the controller layer or an optional service layer.

Comment: ya give absolute path for file.txt but error occurred as configure the SMTP server

Comment: how to split multiple column in single row in jtable in java using netbeans (in design not in coding)

Answer (score 0):

From the error , you posted in the comment `error occurred as configure the SMTP server` , i could see that your host name is invalid.

Try this,

```
   String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
   Properties properties = System.getProperties(); 
   properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
   Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
```

*Note: 
I have used the smtp host name as `gmail` from your **from** address. smtp servers host names changes with mail servers*

Hope this helps